# Is not "binom" latex symbol available in plot via ggplot2/latex2xp

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

I need to write a formula in y axis which uses `binom` sintax in Latex, however, it seems that it is not supported.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
fx.2b <- function(x, theta){
  choose(100, x)*exp((x*log(theta/(1-theta)) + 100*log(1-theta)))
}
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:100, times = 5),
                 theta = rep(c(0.01, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9), each = 100))
df$y <- fx.2b(df$x, df$theta)
df$theta <- as.factor(df$theta)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = theta)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(y = TeX("$f(x; \\theta) = \\binom{100}{x} \\exp (x \\log (\\frac{\\theta}{1-\\theta}) + 100 \\log (1 - \\theta))$"))
```

[image]

My Latex formula is correct:

f(x; \theta) = \binom{100}{x} \exp (x \log (\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}) + 100 \log (1 - \theta))

it display perfectly in https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php.

How can I correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/ to render the latex code rather than using latex2exp to form plotmath code ... (im far from competent at plotmath, but I'm not sure what the plotmath code would be for the binomial dist so perhaps that is the difficulty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `plotmath` directly. From `help("plotmath")`:

> If the text argument to one of the text-drawing functions (text, mtext, axis, legend) in R is an expression, the argument is interpreted as a mathematical expression and the output will be formatted according to TeX-like rules.
>
> . . .
>
> The available features are ... described in the tables below:
>
> Syntax    Meaning
>   . . .
>   atop(x, y)    x over y (no horizontal bar)
>   . . .
>   bgroup("(",atop(x,y),")") use scalable delimiters

So, we can do like so

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = theta)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(y = bquote(bgroup("(", atop(100, x), ")")~"exp(x log"~
                    bgroup("(", frac(theta, 1 - theta), ")")~
                   "+ 100 log(1 -"~theta~"))"))
```

to get binomial type notation

[image]